# Show dates in SQL in asp:Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am wondering if it's possible to have a set of dates in a SQL db and display in in a `<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server">` for a user to select the dates available in a detailsview. Or if there's a better idea of displaying the dates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, you cannot selectively remove dates from the ASP.NET [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, but you can selectively disable dates by handling the [DayRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event: just disable dates 
that are not in the set of dates returned from the database.

You might find a couple online examples helpful taking this approach - [one in Bean Software's ASP.NET FAQ](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Disable-Dates-Calendar.aspx), [another in DotNetSpider's forums](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/324104-How-to-remove-date-in-calendar-control-in-aspnet.aspx).

Here is my stab at what you will need:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    // Disable the date being rendered if it is not in the DB-returned dates (as
    // List<DateTime> _databaseDates).
    if (!_databaseDates.Contains(e.Day.Date))
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.ForeColor = Color.Gray; // or e.Cell.Font.Strikeout = true;
    }
}
```